# Any app like Slingscold or Slingshot Launcher for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

I have trouble installing these apps on the noobslab ppa because it says

```
E:Unable to locate package
```

What I want is a full screen launcher app with translucent background and the ability to edit what apps show up.

Answer (score 1):

I found no way to install slingshot (the one used in elementary os). I tried a lot of guides but none works and compiling from source code is a struggle because of a lot of unmet dependencies... too much software, too much time... But for slingscold this works:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slingscold
```

I think they have recently changed the repository name. It works on Ubuntu 16.10.